# Is there any way to convert non-ascii character to integer and then convert that integer back?

Tags: c++, utf-8

I'm asking if there any way to get the utf-8 character to convert to integer and then convert that integer back to the utf-8 character. I'm sure there is a way to do this with built-in functions but  I will use any external function that will give me result I`m looking for.

This is easy to do with ascii symbols

```
code:

std::cout << (int) 'a' << "\n" << (char) 97;
```

```
output:

97
a
```

However it just doesn`t work with non-ascii symbols

```
code:

std::cout << R"((int) 'Ü' = )" << (int) 'Ü' << "\n";
std::cout << "(char) 50076 = " << (char) 50076 << "\n";
```

```
output:

(int) '├£' = 50076
(char) 50076 = £
```

For some reason 'Ü' was interpreted as multi-character (while compiling I also got warning <warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]> ). And it seemed to only give me the number of the last symbol of multi-character `├£`

I tried to get number of `├` and `£` using the same method as before but they were also  interpreted as multi-character constants.

I thought that maybe the program gave such a result due to the limitations of the `std::cout`
function so I tried to put output in `file.txt`

```
code:

std::ofstream file ("file.txt");
file << 'Ü' << "\n" << "Ü" << (char) 50076;
file.close();
```

this didn`t help me

```
output:

50076
Ãœœ
```

Been stuck with this problem for a while now. I'll take any advice.

Comment: _For some reason 'Ü' was interpreted as multi-character_ That's because (in UTF-8) it _is_ a multi-byte character (or, rather, a multi-byte sequence), is it the corresponding Unicode code point that you're after?

Comment: Multicharacter constants are always handled in an implementation defined manner. Now if you are asking about how to convert a UTF-8 encoded string to an integer or back that would have an answer. Also note that there is no way to do this built in C++ functions. C++ predates the widespread adoption of Unicode and the C++ standards committee has been a long time in catching up.

Comment: The conversion process is carefully explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). It's not too big of a task to implement this for yourself.

Comment: Also try to avoid "C" style casts like `(char)value`,  prefer using `std::static_cast`

Comment: Have you read Wikipedia's article on UTF-8, already? If not, why not? The information in the article gives everything that's needed to do the described task.

Comment: There's no good built-in way of dealing with UTF-8. You either find a library, or do the bit manipulation by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are wanting is transcoding between `UTF-8` and `UTF-32`. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a good resource for a general explanation.

There are several existing libraries that support this operation. Among the full-featured options are [icu](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/) and [boost](https://www.boost.org). For just transcoding, the header-only [UTF8-CPP](https://utfcpp.sourceforge.net) library is a lightweight option.

If these don't meet your requirements, the following code demonstrates how to do the transcoding from codepoints in the range `0x0000'0000` to `0x0010'FFFF` with a small amount of code. Since the code does not map all `uint32_t` values map to  `utf-8` sequences, error checking would need to be added.

### Sample Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using std::cout, std::endl;

template<class Iterator>
void codepoint_to_utf8(uint32_t code, Iterator iter) {
    if (code <= 0x007F) {
        *iter++ = static_cast<uint8_t>(code bitand 0x7F);
    }
    else if (code <= 0x07FF) {
        *iter++ = 0xC0 bitor static_cast<uint8_t>((code >> 6) bitand 0x1F);
        *iter++ = 0x80 bitor static_cast<uint8_t>(code bitand 0x3F);
    }
    else if (code <= 0xFFFF) {
        *iter++ = 0xE0 bitor static_cast<uint8_t>((code >> 12) bitand 0x0F);
        *iter++ = 0x80 bitor static_cast<uint8_t>((code >> 6) bitand 0x3F);
        *iter++ = 0x80 bitor static_cast<uint8_t>(code bitand 0x3F);
    }
    else if (code <= 0x10'FFFF) {
        *iter++ = 0xF0 bitor static_cast<uint8_t>((code >> 18) bitand 0x07);
        *iter++ = 0x80 bitor static_cast<uint8_t>((code >> 12) bitand 0x3F);
        *iter++ = 0x80 bitor static_cast<uint8_t>((code >> 6) bitand 0x3F);
        *iter++ = 0x80 bitor static_cast<uint8_t>(code bitand 0x3F);
    }
}

template<class Iterator>
uint32_t utf8_sequence_to_codepoint(Iterator iter) {
    auto byte = static_cast<uint32_t>(*iter++);
    if (byte <= 0x7F) {
        return byte;
    }
    else if ((byte bitand 0xE0) == 0xC0) {
        uint32_t r = (byte bitand 0x1F) << 6;
        r |= static_cast<uint32_t>(*iter++) bitand 0x3F;
        return r;
    }
    else if ((byte bitand 0xF0) == 0xE0) {
        uint32_t r = (byte bitand 0x0F) << 12;
        r |= (static_cast<uint32_t>(*iter++) bitand 0x3F) << 6;
        r |= static_cast<uint32_t>(*iter++) bitand 0x3F;
        return r;
    }
    else if ((byte bitand 0xF8) == 0xF0) {
        uint32_t r = (byte bitand 0x07) << 18;
        r |= (static_cast<uint32_t>(*iter++) bitand 0x3F) << 12;
        r |= (static_cast<uint32_t>(*iter++) bitand 0x3F) << 6;
        r |= static_cast<uint32_t>(*iter++) bitand 0x3F;
        return r;
    }
    else
        return 0xFFFF'FFFF;
}

void examine(uint32_t code) {
    std::string str;
    codepoint_to_utf8(code, std::back_inserter(str));
    cout << std::hex << code << " = " << str << " = ";
    cout << std::hex << utf8_sequence_to_codepoint(str.begin()) << endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    examine(0x0024);
    examine(0x00A3);
    examine(0x0418);
    examine(0x0939);
    examine(0x20AC);
    examine(0xD55C);
    examine(0x1'0348);
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
24 = $ = 24
a3 = £ = a3
418 = И = 418
939 = ह = 939
20ac = € = 20ac
d55c = 한 = d55c
10348 =  = 10348
```